# Node/Tedious not triggering "done" event

Tags: javascript, node.js, tedious

I've started learning Node and am using Tedious to connect to and query a DB.

I've written a module, `db`, which exports the following functions:

```
exports.connect = function(callback) {
    console.log("\n** 1. open db");
    db = new Connection(local.config.db_config);
    db.on("connect", callback);
};

exports.disconnect = function(callback) {
    console.log("db.disconnect");
    if (!db) {
        return;
    }

    db.on("close", callback);
};

exports.query = function(cbQuery, cbRow, cbDone) {
    var Request = require("tedious").Request,
        request = new Request("SELECT * FROM Clients", cbQuery);

    if (typeof(cbRow) === "function") {
        request.on("row", cbRow);
    }

    if (typeof(cbDone) === "function") {
        request.on("done", cbDone);
    }

    db.execSql(request);
};
```

I then have the standard `server.js` in which I call those exported functions using the following:

```
var dbConnected = function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("** FATAL ERROR ON CONNECT: ");
            console.error(err);
            process.exit(-1);
        }
        console.log("DB connected");

        db.query(dbQueryCallback, dbOnRows, dbOnDone);
    },
    dbDisconnected = function (err) {
        console.log("dbDisconnected");
        if (err) {
            console.error("** FATAL ERROR ON DISCONNECT: ");
            console.error(err);
            process.exit(-1);
        }

        console.log("DB disconnected");
    },
    dbQueryCallback = function (err, rowCount, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("ERROR DURING QUERY:");
            console.error(err);
            process.exit(-1);
        }
        console.log("Query rowCount = " + rowCount);
    },
    dbOnRows = function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            if (column.value === null) {
                console.log("NULL");
            } else {
                console.log(column.metadata.colName + ": " + column.value);
            }
        });
    },
    dbOnDone = function(rowCount, more, rows) {
        console.log("done");

        db.disconnect(dbDisconnected);
    };

db.connect(dbConnected);
```

When run, the DB connection is successfully opened, a simple query is executed and its results are written to the console (by the `dbOnRows` handler).

However, the `dbOnDone` handler is never triggered, so the connection is never closed.

Can anyone explain why `dbOnDone` is not being triggered?

Comment: Are we talking about https://github.com/pekim/tedious/blob/master/examples/minimal.js ? `connection.close()` is invoked as part of `executeStatement` method …

Comment: Um... did you look at the JavaScript which I provided in my question? It's not the same as the example JavaScript which you've referenced.

Comment: Yes, I've looked into and I tried to compare it to `Tedious` - For e.g. in Tedious there is no event like `.close`. Is this from some documentation?

Comment: The `close` event is detailed on this page: http://pekim.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html  But anyway, the `close` event is not my problem; my question was primarily *why is the `dbOnDone` event not being triggered?*

Answer (score 3):

Partly solved this problem. I switched from 'done' to 'doneProc' and now i do receive this event after the last 'row' event was fired, but without the 'rows 'argument (somehow it comes empty) even though i set the connection with the config.options.rowCollectionOnDone = true as mentioned in http://pekim.github.io/tedious/api-request.html. So to get the results i still use the 'row' event and the global 'jsonArray' variable, but now at least i  know when this 'jsonArray' is ready for use. here is the code:

```
var jsonArray = [];

function selectStatement(sql,callback) {

    request = new Request(sql, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    //reset the jsonArray
    jsonArray = [];

    request.on('row', function (columns) {
        var rowObject = {};
        columns.forEach(function (column) {
            if (column.value === null) {
                console.log('NULL');
            } else {

                rowObject[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
            }
        });

        jsonArray.push(rowObject);

    });

    request.on('doneProc', function (rowCount, more, returnStatus, rows) {
        //console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
        console.log(rows) // this is the full array of row objects
    });

    connection.execSql(request);
}
```